# Could not find a delimiter after string delimiter

Tags: azure, blob, azure-data-factory, polybase

I am trying to load data into polybase table from csv flat file having `"/,/|/^` data into it.

I have create file format with the `(STRING_DELIMITER = '"')`

```
CREATE EXTERNAL FILE FORMAT StringDelimiter WITH (
    FORMAT_TYPE = DELIMITEDTEXT,
    FORMAT_OPTIONS (
        FIELD_TERMINATOR = ',',
        STRING_DELIMITER = '"',
        FIRST_ROW = 2,
        ENCODING = 'UTF8'
) );
```

But i got an error while fetching from blob storage:

> HdfsBridge::recordReaderFillBuffer - Unexpected error encountered filling record reader buffer: HadoopExecutionException: Could not find a delimiter after string delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the escape character support is not yet available in synapse while loading using Polybase.

You can convert CSV flat file to Parquet file format in data factory.

Then to CREATE EXTERNAL FILE FORMAT use following query

```
CREATE EXTERNAL FILE FORMAT table_name
WITH
(  
    FORMAT_TYPE = PARQUET,
    DATA_COMPRESSION = 'org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec'
)
```

Reference link1- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/118102/polybase-load-csv-file-that-contains-text-column-w.html

Reference link2- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/develop-tables-external-tables?tabs=hadoop#arguments-for-create-external-file-format